# Does helm upgrade runs a Job post-install even if no update to values.yaml?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod

I have scripts that are mounted to a shared persistent volume. Part of the main Deployment chart is to run some bash scripts in the `initContainers` that will clone the scripts repository and copy/mount it to the shared persistent volume. My issue is sometimes there will be no changes in the main app or no update to the values.yaml file, so no helm upgrade will actually happen. I think this is fine but what I want to happen is have a task that will still clone the scripts repository and copy/mount it to the persistent volume.

I am reading about k8s Job (post-install hook) but I am not sure if this will accomplish what I need.

Comment: If I understood correctly, you need execute the `initContainer` scripts every time you run `helm upgrade` even if no updates was made in application or `values.yaml` file. Is it correct? The `initContainers` only will run once when the pod is created, if you want to run it again you need to destroy the container and recreate. You could try to use the [--force flag](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_upgrade/#options) in `helm upgrade` command to recreate all resources. If you could explain in more details your use case will be very useful to get more help.

Comment: Yes. `initContainers` are executing just fine in the Deployment resource. It also detects changes in the configmap/secrets. The script that is executed in the `initContainers` is a `git clone` a script repo. Brance name (eg. master) is specified. If changes are made to values/configmaps, it deploys fine during the `helm upgrade`. But something change in the master branch of the scripts repo, if your re-run `helm upgrade`, helm don't detect any changes so no deployment will happen. It does not know if something change in the master branch, unless I specify a different branch name to clone.

Comment: I confirmed that Job will not run the post-install hook if there are no changes. The `helm history` will still register the deployment since a new entry with new revision number is added.

Comment: So I guess since the intent is to force a job to run regardless of whether a deployment happen or not, I wonder if there is a hook (not pre-install or post-install) that I can use to indicate to run this job regardless of helm upgrade status.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not changed anything in HELM side like values or spec/templates, the HELM will not perform any change.
In this case your code is a external source and looking by HELM perspective it is correct.

I can propose some alternatives to achieve what you want:

1. **Use HELM with FORCE flag**
   Use `helm upgrade --force` to upgrade your deployment. 
   By Helm [docs](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_upgrade/):

   > **--force** - force resource updates through a replacement strategy

In this case Helm will recreate all resources of your chart, consequently the pods, and then re-run `initContainers` executing your script again.

2. **Use a Kubernetes CronJob**
   In this case you will spawn a pod that will mount your volume and run a script/command you want.

Example of a [Kubernetes CronJob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/):

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: nice-count
spec:
  schedule: "*/2 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: nice-job
            image: alpine
            command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo "HelloWorld" > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html']
            volumeMounts:
              - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
                name: task-pv-storage
          volumes:
            - name: task-pv-storage
              persistentVolumeClaim:
                claimName: task-pv-claim
          restartPolicy: Never
```

In this example, a CronJob will run **each 2 hours**, mounting the volume `task-pv-storage` on `/usr/share/nginx/html` and executing the command `echo "HelloWorld" > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html`.

You should trigger the CronJob mannually creating a Job with the command:

```
kubectl create job --from=cronjob/<CRON_JOB_NAME> <JOB_NAME>
```

In the example above, the command looks like this:

`kubectl create job --from=cronjob/nice-count nice-count-job`

3. **Execute a Job manually or using CI/CD**
   You can execute the job directly or if you have a CI/CD solution you can create a job to run once instead use a CronJob, in this case you should use this template:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: nice-count-job
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: alpine
        name: my-job
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html
          name: task-pv-storage
        command:
        - sh
        - -c
        - echo "hello" > /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
      restartPolicy: Never
      volumes:
      - name: task-pv-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: task-pv-claim
```

I've tested this examples and works in both cases.

Please let me know if that helped!

Comment: The `Job` with a post-install hook is what I did already which did not really trigger since in helm perspective there was no change. So I think what I can do is to have a flag whether to run this `Job` or not. In the yaml, I will have the if condition in the beginning. From `help upgrade` command, i will pass a value like `--set run_nice-count-job=true`